# Understanding inner classes in trait

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to Scala and now I'm trying to learn how to write tests in `Scalatest`. Here is an example [***they provided***](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers) with the using custom matchers section:

```
import org.scalatest._
import matchers._

trait CustomMatchers {

    class FileEndsWithExtensionMatcher(expectedExtension: String) extends Matcher[java.io.File] {
        def apply(left: java.io.File) = {
            val name = left.getName
            MatchResult(
                name.endsWith(expectedExtension),
                s"""File $name did not end with extension "$expectedExtension"""",
                s"""File $name ended with extension "$expectedExtension"""""
            )
        }
    }

def endWithExtension(expecedExtension: String) = new FileEndsWithExtensionMatcher(expectedExtension)

}

// Make them easy to import with:
// import CustomMatchers._
object CustomMatchers extends CustomMatchers
```

I do not quite understand the reason they pu the `FileEndsWithExtensionMatcher` class into a trait? Why? Is it idiomatic scala way or some? Can't you explain it?

Answer (score 3):

It is just for your convienience.
That is one of many ways to modularize your code and than reuse it in desired suites. You can organize it in packages or objects and it will work either. With this approach it is just easy to mix traits into your tests. What's more it allows you to nicely organize connected matchers.

For example you can create trait with group of matchers for currencies and another trait matching physical units. Next you can mixin one or both traits into your Test.

Comment: A small clarification about your last paragraph. You mean to create some small traits than mix them into two larger traits and then mix the two large traits into my Test. Right?

Comment: It is actually up to you how you want to organize it. You can leave two small traits and mixin them directly into your Test. But if you plan to use them together a lot, just join them in another bigger trait.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose here is to "put all the matchers into one place from which you can easily access them in other code". You could put all these traits into a package and import that package. But the link you reference states that "One good way to organize custom matchers is to place them inside one or more traits that you can then mix into the suites that need them". It would work either way. It's just a matter of preference.